# Is it possible to make multiple adb commands a one-liner command? (case change bootanimation.zip)

Tags: adb, root-access, shell

Is it possible to make the following commands a one-liner command ? to change bootanimation.zip quickly and gain some

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>adb push bootanimation /sdcard
C:\Users\User\Desktop>adb shell
$ su
# mount -o rw,remount /system
# cp /sdcard/bootanimation.zip /system/media/bootanimation.zip
# chmod 644 /system/media/bootanimation.zip
# reboot
```

Regards

Comment: Why not put your desired commands inside a shell script and simply invoke that?

Comment: To whom it may concern! Consider adding a comment when down-voting!

Answer (score 1):

Much like @CzarMatt I'd suggest saving the commands ya want run within the Android device to a shell script such as `adb_boot_animation_copy.sh` on your PC...

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if ! [ -f "/sdcard/bootanimation.zip" ]; then
    printf 'No can do\n' >&2
    exit 1
fi

su || exit "$?"
mount -o rw,remount /system

cp /sdcard/bootanimation.zip /system/media/bootanimation.zip
chmod 644 /system/media/bootanimation.zip
reboot
```

> Tip, `#!/usr/bin/env sh` is more portable than `#!/bin/sh`... this is not just because the Android dev. team thought it was a *good idea* to move things about when adopting Linux into Android, there are other *unixish* OSs that also got *clever* with where one can find an executable shell.

... then use redirection with either `<` or `cat`...

```
adb shell "$(cat "adb_boot_animation_copy.sh")"
```

Which essentially does the typing of the commands saved within the *`adb_boot_animation_copy.sh`* file for ya. Though I'm not certain that this kind of redirection will work on MS bound devices without some modifications.

### Update

Another way to redirect output of one command into the input of another...

```
cat adb_boot_animation_copy.sh | adb shell
```

> Note PowerShell **does** have the `cat` command, though ya might want to edit the file path from the above examples to be an absolute file path.

... which *should* result in the same behavior of redirecting commands from the `adb_boot_animation_copy.sh` file into the `adb shell`.

And yet another way would be to use the `FOR \?` syntax within a `batch` script...

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`type adb_boot_animation_copy.sh`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
)
```

... to save the continence of a file to a variable for later redirection into `adb`, eg something like *`adb shell "%var%"`*, or use `type` in place of `cat` and `>`/`<` instead of `|`...

```
type adb_boot_animation_copy.sh > adb shell
```

If ya run into issues leave a comment and perhaps I'll make another edit with more ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: He used windows os.

Comment: @M.Rostami considering that PowerShell also has the `cat` command I don't think ya can blame me for the OP's reliance on MS products, nor should this answer be down voted as it is correct for _Unix'ish_ devices and only requires a small amount of adjustment to likely get something that operates similarly on MS devices.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I figured out how to do it in a one-liner adb command from Windows CMD Shell:

```
adb push bootanimation.zip /sdcard & adb shell "su -c 'mount -o rw,remount /system & rm /system/media/bootanimation.zip & cp /sdcard/bootanimation.zip /system/media & chmod 644 /system/media/bootanimation.zip & reboot'"
```

In order to make this one line useful in a **batch file use && instead of &**

```
adb push bootanimation.zip /sdcard && adb shell "su -c 'mount -o rw,remount /system && rm /system/media/bootanimation.zip && cp /sdcard/bootanimation.zip /system/media && chmod 644 /system/media/bootanimation.zip && reboot'"
```

Thank you for your time & contributions!

Comment: In short that's _gross_. And I think this should have been added to your answer as an edit so that readers can help ya in writing something saner, because what you've got there at the moment is **not** easily maintained, documented, debugged, or extended/edited.

Comment: I assume that you're one of the down-voters, but sorry your reply is out of the scope of the question and it's linux specific! cheers!

Comment: That would be your assumption... As for my reply/answer, if ya re-check it you'll find that there's been some MS related additions for how to do similar with _non-Unix_ like Operating Systems, while also allowing for future debugging and/or expansion of features. Additionally if ya dig deeper into Android you'll find that it's based on the Linux Kernel and has many of the same utilities when at the _`shell`_ level... though with some rather annoying differences of behavior, options, and file paths. Best of luck avoiding disaster with your endeavors.